# What is community wiki question?

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What is the purpose of community wiki questions? Why are they any different from standard question? What kind of question should be a community wiki question?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23940/what-is-community-wiki-question?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a feature from Askbot. [This question](https://askbot.org/en/question/6643/what-is-the-intention-of-community-wiki-questions/) should help clarify it's intended use.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0